# Change to polar coordinates when evaluating limits of functions in two variables?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have a function in two variables $f(x, y)$ and need to calculate the limit $$ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (2, 3)}{f(x, y)} .$$ If I decide to change to polar coordinates, how can I determine where $r$ tends to?

I was thinking, since $r = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$, on evaluating $$ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (2, 3)}{r} = \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (2, 3)}{ \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} = \sqrt{13},$$ and then writing $$ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (2, 3)}{f(x, y)} = \lim_{r \rightarrow \sqrt{13}}{f(r \cos{\theta}, r \sin{\theta})} .$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the function in question? Or is it just for some arbitrary function in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: You should add $\theta \to \arctan \frac{3}{2}$ to the limit.

Comment: @jnh Well there is not a particular function I have in mind, I was just curious 'cause in all the exercises I have found in my book $(x, y)$ tends to $(0, 0)$ so $r$ tends to $0$ too. I want to know how to handle this other case.

Comment: You can disregard $\theta$ **only** when  $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct because $r=\sqrt{13}$ means all points that are $\sqrt{13}$ units away of the center.
You can do a translation of the $R^2$ plane by the vector (2,3). Than f(x,y) would be f(x-2,y-3) and r->0.

Comment: How can I determine where $r$ tends to then?

Comment: After translation of the plain for the vector (2,3) every point with coordinates (x,y) in the first coordinate system would be (x-2,y-3) on the new coordinate system, so the point (2,3) in the first coordinate system would be (0,0) for the second one. Than you can use the standard form for polar coordinates, and since (x,y) will tend to (0,0), it means that r tends to 0.